# How can I make an speech box with an right angle triangle (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div look a little like a speech box with a triangle at the top left, currently I have this:

```css
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 240px;
height: 120px;
padding: 12px;
background: brown;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 17px 23px 17px 0;
border-color: transparent brown;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -23px;
top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

And I am looking to have it like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 240px;
height: 120px;
padding: 12px;
background: brown;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 23px 17px 0;
border-color: transparent brown;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -23px;
top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Here try this one, i removed the border-top in your style, so it goes like this, `border-width: 0px 23px 17px 0;`. Let me know if this is what youre aiming for.

EDIT: By the way if you want to make some adjustments to that triangle you can adjust the `border-right` and `border-bottom` to make it look like what you've shown in your image.

Comment: Arrh god damn I missed that totally! Thanks. Also that works as needed but I have a profile image on the left of it, what is the best way to stop it from going on top of the image as it touches it?

Comment: You could increase the z-index of the image so it appears on top :) Also this may be helpful for learning how to create CSS triangles: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: Cheers, sorry to be a pain but I meant so that the triangle is not touching the profile image on the left if that makes sense :)

Comment: frankly, im not that good at css but if I will be answering your question my best option for you is to add padding-left to the bubble, and just make sure that both profile pic and bubble are on the same row.